# C++: Is there any way to have conditional operators based on a value in order to simplify blocks of code?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, simplify

Say, for example:

```
if(CurrentRotationStage % 2 == 0)
{
    if(FMath::CubicInterpDerivative(CubicPoint[CurrentRotationStage], 0.f, CubicPoint[(CurrentRotationStage + 1) % 4], 0.f, MainMenuWidget->TrumpAngle / RotationLimit) < 0.f)
    {
        CurrentRotationStage = ++CurrentRotationStage % 4;
        MainMenuWidget->TrumpAngle -= RotationLimit;
    }
}
else
{
    if(FMath::CubicInterpDerivative(CubicPoint[CurrentRotationStage], 0.f, CubicPoint[(CurrentRotationStage + 1) % 4], 0.f, MainMenuWidget->TrumpAngle / RotationLimit) > 0.f)
    {
        CurrentRotationStage = ++CurrentRotationStage % 4;
        MainMenuWidget->TrumpAngle -= RotationLimit;
    }
}
```

Basically, if CurrentRotationStage is even, I want to use < in my if statement, and the opposite if it's odd. Is there any way to simplify this in order to prevent the use of multiple if/elses?

Comment: what if `CubicInterpDerivative == 0`?

Comment: It would be fine, nothing should happen, values need to change after the derivative changes sign from positive to negative, or negative to positive, depending on the stage.

Comment: These are all good answers that addressed different things I was unaware of/slipped my mind, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you want a switchable operator, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::function<bool(int,int)> op = std::less<int>();
    std::cout << "Defaulting to less-than" << std::endl;

    int x = 5;
    if (x & 1) {
        op = std::greater<int>();
        std::cout << "Chosing greater-than because number is odd" << std::endl;
    }

    if (op(x, 4)) {
        std::cout << x << " is op(4)" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know you could do something like that, thanks.

Comment: Can the compiler optimize this as well as if the native operator were used?

Comment: @ChrisBetti , no, since you're switching operator based on a runtime value. The optimized solution is something like ergonaut posted - simplify the overall code. But when one truly wants runtime choice without code duplication, one can get it.

Answer (score 4):

This part should be put in a variable.

```
(FMath::CubicInterpDerivative(CubicPoint[CurrentRotationStage], 0.f, CubicPoint[(CurrentRotationStage + 1) % 4], 0.f, MainMenuWidget->TrumpAngle / RotationLimit)
```

Then it would look like this:

```
blah = calculateIt...
if(CurrentRotationStage % 2 == 0 && blah < 0.f) ||
 (CurrentRotationStage % 2 != 0 && blah > 0.f){
    CurrentRotationStage = ++CurrentRotationStage % 4;
    MainMenuWidget->TrumpAngle -= RotationLimit;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for reminding me to do that, though I was curious about conditional statements with operators if my use case was extended to have multiple different cases, which would make for a very large conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the comparison logic into a common function or class

```
class RotationChecker
{
public:
    explicit RotationChecker(int stage): stage_(stage) {}
    bool operator()(float f) const { return stage % 2 == 0 ? f < 0.f : f > 0.f; }
private:
    int stage_;
};

RotationChecker checker(CurrentRotationStage);
float value = FMath::CubicInterpDerivative(CubicPoint[CurrentRotationStage], 0.f,
    CubicPoint[(CurrentRotationStage + 1) % 4], 0.f,
    MainMenuWidget->TrumpAngle / RotationLimit);
if (checker(value)))  // or "if (RotationChecker(CurrentRotationStage)(value))"
{
    CurrentRotationStage = ++CurrentRotationStage % 4;
    MainMenuWidget->TrumpAngle -= RotationLimit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take the approach from a few of the existing answers:

```
std::function<bool (int, int)> fn = std::less<int>();
if (CurrentRotationStage % 2 == 0)
{
    fn = std::greater<int>();
}

float result = FMath::CubicInterpDerivative(CubicPoint[CurrentRotationStage], 0.f, CubicPoint[(CurrentRotationStage + 1) % 4], 0.f, MainMenuWidget->TrumpAngle / RotationLimit);

if (fn(result, 0.f))
{
    CurrentRotationStage = ++CurrentRotationStage % 4;
    MainMenuWidget->TrumpAngle -= RotationLimit;
}
```